# This code doesnot work on devC++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *p;
    *p=9;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this code not executing in devc++?

Comment: you could say `int *p = new int;` to fix it

Answer (score 5):

You never allocated any memory for `p` so you have an uninitialized pointer pointing to garbage.  Once you dereference it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

```
int *p;
```

Should be

```
int *p = new int;
```

And then you need a

```
delete p;
```

before the end of main as every `new`/`new[]` should be matched with a `delete`/`delete[]`.

But in this case there is no reason to even do that.  Just use a regular int and you have

```
int main()
{
    int p = 9;
    std::cout<< p << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nathan, but following your line of thought, threre is no reason to even do that! The program is going to always output 9, so it is fair to replace it with `echo 9`.

Comment: @SergeyA I was included changing to using int to show that you can create variables without `new`.  I see a few people who do this as they came from java and they think everything should be `new`ed up.